# Where are windows8 Menus / Icons font-sizes stored in registry

Tags: windows-8-fonts

I can manually change the font-sizes from this windows 8 control-panel window.

[image]

But I need to automate this process with AutoHotKey, so I can basically have two different menus/icons/title-bar font-sizes profiles. So when I'm outputting to HDTV, I can have bigger menus  / icons text etc. and when back on laptop screen, I can have the smaller font sizes (that are defaults).

Where are these values stored in registry?